# Help with an IF in SQL SERVER Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

can anyone help me with construction of an IF in a stored procedure in sql server.

Basically I have a simple stored procedure but I now need to pass in a new input parameter which depending if it is true I pass the value D and if its false I pass the value A. But the change is in the middle of a subquery.. let me explain... here is the stored procedure. basically if I send in True for ReturnOldStatus I execute the subquery ItemStatus='D' and if it is false then i pass in ItemStatus='A'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyTempStoredProc]
(
 @IdOffice                                 Int,
 @ReturnOldStatus                           bit
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   SELECT * FROM Offices

   WHERE
      IdOffice = @IdOffice  

      AND (V.OffType NOT IN (
                        SELECT *  FROM MiscOff 
                        WHERE
ItemStatus= 'D') // This needs to be ItemStatus ='A' if FALSE is passed in on the input param
```

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would solve it like this:

```
    declare @itemStatus varchar(1);
    if (@inputParam = 'FALSE')
    begin
        set @itemStatus = 'A'
    end
    else
        set @itemStatus = 'D'

   SELECT * FROM Offices
   WHERE
          IdOffice = @IdOffice      
          AND (V.OffType NOT IN (
                   SELECT *  FROM MiscOff 
                   WHERE ItemStatus= @itemStatus) 
              )
```

T-Sql is not my native language, so there may be errors in there...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the T-SQL [if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717(SQL.90).aspx) statement:

```
IF @ReturnOldStatus = 0
    BEGIN
        --Some statements
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        --Some other statements
    END
```

Comment: thanks but this would mean i need to duplicate the sql statements wouldn't it..??

Comment: Correct, most of the SQL would have to be duplicated. There are other options, depending on exactly what you need to accomplish. The answer from Frederik does not require code duplication and appears to also solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will suffice for your problem.  If not, look into the DECLARE/SET statements in TSQL.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyTempStoredProc] 
    (@IdOffice Int, 
     @ReturnOldStatus bit ) 
AS BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 

    SELECT * FROM Offices 
    WHERE IdOffice = @IdOffice  
          AND (V.OffType NOT IN (SELECT * FROM MiscOff 
                                 WHERE (ItemStatus= 'D' AND @ReturnOldStatus = 1)
                                         OR
                                       (ItemStatus= 'A' AND @ReturnOldStatus = 0) 
                                )
```